# How to handle possible query rows limits in batch class

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits

We have a process in which we  delete all the records of a custom sObject, and then create new ones using data from other sObjects. Since the query can reach limits, we decided to create a batch class.

This is the code for my batch class:

```java
public with sharing class BatchApexUpdOutsProv implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    
    public BatchApexUpdOutsProv() {}

    public static Iterable<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return [SELECT Id FROM Outstanding__c WHERE Proveedores__c = TRUE];
    }

    public static void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Outstanding__c> scope){
        List<Outstanding__c> out_delete = new List<Outstanding__c>();
                  
        for(Outstanding__c  out: scope){
            out_delete.add(new Outstanding__c  (id = out.id));
        }

        delete out_delete;
    }

    public static void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        List<Outstanding__c> out_insert = new List<Outstanding__c>();

        List<Supplier_Invoice__c> sis = [SELECT id, Company_1__c, Supplier__c, Date__c, name, Total_Amount__c FROM Supplier_Invoice__c];
                
        for(Supplier_Invoice__c si: sis){
            out_insert.add(new Outstanding__c  (Company__c = si.Company_1__c, Cuenta__c = si.Supplier__c, Supplier_Invoice__c = si.id, Date__c = si.Date__c, 
                                                Total_Credit_Amount__c = si.Total_Amount__c, Credit__c = si.Total_Amount__c, ID__c = si.name, Debit__c = 0, Proveedores__c = TRUE));
        }

        List<Debit__c> dbs = [SELECT id, Company__c, Supplier__c, Date__c, name, Amount__c, Adv_PAY_ID__c, Supp_INV_ID__c FROM Debit__c];
                
        for(Debit__c db: dbs){
            out_insert.add(new Outstanding__c  (Company__c = db.Company__c, Cuenta__c = db.Supplier__c, Debit1__c = db.id, Date__c = db.Date__c, 
                                                Total_Credit_Amount__c = 0, Credit__c = 0, ID__c = db.name, Supplier_Invoice__c = db.Supp_INV_ID__c, 
                                                Debit__c = db.Amount__c, Total_Debt_Amount__c = db.Amount__c, Proveedores__c = TRUE, Advanced_Payment__c = db.Adv_PAY_ID__c));
        }

        insert out_insert;  

        System.debug('Proceso de actualización de Outstanding (proveedores) completado');
    }
}
```

There is another batch just like this one but in the finish(), the processing is a little more complex (more records involved of more sObjects, but the logic is the same).

The thing is, with this class I am able to delete all the records I want in batches, but this is only the first part of the process. The next part in which I generate the new records by querying other objects, could potentially reach row limits, but I'm a little confused as to how solve this.

What I thought for a solution is to create a separate batch class for each object I'm creating records from (for instance, a separate batch class to create Outstanding records from Supplier Invoice, and another batch class to create from Debit records, etc) and then executing them from the finish method.

But is it correct to do this that way? Is there another way to process ALL the records without separating every piece of logic into different batches?

Comment: why can't the finish() logic be moved into each execute() transaction?  Also, your `execute()` can be simplified to one line `delete scope;`

Comment: @cropredy because I don't want that logic with all those queries to be called for each time the execute() method is fired. The logic I put in the finish() method is there because it should be called only one time, after all the records are deleted. My problem is if all those queries reach the 50.000 rows limit and how to avoid it.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the queries for `Supplier_Invoice__c` and `Debit__c` ? As written, these are fetching every row. But within a given `execute()`, there must be some contextual data to help limit the scope of these queries  - perhaps a Date field or some Id fields?